# Как можно скопировать все текстовые файлы (.txt) из каталога ~/source в каталог ~/destination?

Tags: linux, ос

Как можно скопировать все текстовые файлы (.txt) из каталога ~/source в каталог ~/destination? ОС LINUX

Comment: `cp ~/source/*.txt ~/destination`

Comment: `rsync -avrhuP --include=*.txt --exclude=* ~/source/ ~/destination/`